# Fast diag(A*C*B') in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, matrix, diagonal

Is there a fast way to calculate `a*C*b` for many pairs `(a,b)` of vectors?

For example here 6 vectors `a` and `b` are stored in the matrices `A` and `B` respectively:

```
A = rand(5,6)';
C = rand(5,3);
B = rand(3,6)';

diag(A*C*B')
```

or

```
dot((A*C)',B')
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: A has 30 values, and B 18 in your case...not 6.

Comment: Are lowercase `a` and `b` matrices or scalars?

Comment: Are `A`, `B`, and `C` really random matrices? Or do they have any special properties?

Comment: But the `dot` version is already faster than the `diag` version, so do you mean even faster?

Comment: @horchler no special properties.